# automate copying files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need some help in getting something to be copied with a shell liner or so ..

example

```
cp QA/Release/apps/offline/config/logging.yml     Production/Release/apps/offline/config/logging.yml
cp QA/Release/config/nc_databases_dev.yml         Production/Release/config/nc_databases_dev.yml
cp QA/Release/config/nc_databases_live.yml        Production/Release/config/nc_databases_live.yml
cp QA/Release/config/nc_databases_live_dev.yml    Production/Release/config/nc_databases_live_dev.yml
cp QA/Release/config/nc_databases_test.yml        Production/Release/config/nc_databases_test.yml
cp QA/Release/config/nc_databases_va.yml          Production/Release/config/nc_databases_va.yml
```

if you see the I am copying  QA/files..  to Production/files.. just the first 2 directories change  QA to Production , rest of the paths remain the same .

I could get this far , write the filenames in a file and read it, then copy

```
for i in `cat file ` ; do  cp  $i to ?????  ; done
```

copy $i to Production as it reads each source line , but just need to remove QA/ as it copies on the fly ..

Thanks

Comment: Are you copying everything in the `QA/Release/config` folder to the `Production/Release/config` folder? Or are there things you don't need to copy?

Comment: If you remove the QA/ start, something like `cp QA/$i Production/$i` should do the trick.

Comment: Is "shell liner" supposed to be "shell one-liner"?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look to [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) ? Something like this should do the stuff :

```
rsync -a --include '*.yml' QA/Release Production/Release/
```

EDIT: test and correct the rsync line.

This command will copy everything found under the QA/Release directories that respects the pattern '*.yml' into the Porduction/Release tree. A `QA/Release/x/y/z/file.yml` will be copied in `Production/Release/x/y/z/file.yml`

Comment: rsync won't help because the source paths change something like       QA/dir/dir1/file  Production/dir/dir1/file  and QA/dir/dir1/file1  Production/dir/dir1/file1    or QA/dir/dir2/file1  Production/dir/dir2/file1    ...

Comment: @Ganaiwali : I don't understand how the change occurs, could you give us a few more examples ?

Comment: @Brian   yes I copy the files from  QA/Release/config folder to the Production/Release/config folder . Also the Source will all be some thing like QA/dir/file Production/dir/file  or it could change to QA/dir/xyz Production/dir/xyz

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just the same as copying the directory and renaming it?

```
cp -r QA Production
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r name
do
    cp "$name" "PRODUCTION/${name#QA/}"
done < file
```

As a one-liner:

```
while read -r name; do cp "$name" "PRODUCTION/${name#QA/}"; done < file
```